# Boyer-Moore-Algorithm pattern

Tags: algorithms

Trying to find a pattern of length 8 using only letters a and b such that the number of comparisons in Boyer-Moore Algorithm is as large as possible. Doing all of this without the string given

Any tips on how to approach this, I understand how the bad character rule works but can't seem to make any progress.

Comment: Look into minimizing the shift distances.